# Is it possible to paste excel data from clipboard to tk table?

Tags: tcl

Is it possible to paste excel data from clipboard to table in tcl. I am copying 3x2 cells from excel sheet and trying to paste it in table. If this possible then which command to be used?

Comment: I'm rather positive that the answer is no. But you might consider hooking into Windows API to get the "rich" clipboard contents.

Comment: You ought to be able to achieve what you're after using the tcom interface to read the data directly from Excel. Not quite what you're after, but looking on the bright side, you'd save a keysroke/mouse action, since you would only have to select the cells, in the spreadsheet and wouldn't need to cut/copy them as well :-). Good luck!

Comment: Couldn't you just use Tk's clipboard get command? http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/clipboard.htm . When I tried it, the data that I copied from my Excel sheet appear in Tcl as tab-separated plain text lines. Failing that simple approach, there is also Tcom - http://wiki.tcl.tk/11900

Comment: I assume you are using [Tktable](http://tktable.sourceforge.net/tktable/doc/tkTable.html)? If you adjust the `-rowseparator` and `-colseparator` correctly you certainly can cut and paste.